# MySQL SUM for Persian numbers not working

Tags: php, mysql

I have a DB and Tables with collation utf8_general_ci (all of them) and charset utf8 (all of them) ...
In this table:

### [image: Screenshot from PHPMyAdmin]

and with this PHP code:

```
$query = "SELECT SUM(carpet_rows) AS cr_sum FROM form1";
if ($result = mysqli_query($db,$query)) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    echo $row['cr_sum'];
}
```

I want to see ۳۵۰۰
but I see zero?!